# Getting an entire value from XML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

How do I get the entire result from XML using simplexml_load_string?

My XML looks like this

```
<xml>
    <code>
      <codedesc>Code Name</codedesc>
      100
    </code>
    <code>
      <codedesc>Code Name 2</codedesc>
      200
    </code>
</xml>
```

When I load it with PHP using this code

```
$XML = simplexml_load_string($data);
print_r($XML);
```

I only get codedesc and not the code number as you can see here

https://eval.in/51562

Comment: You should probably be wrapping that number in it's own XML tag so that it can be easily identified.

Comment: Numeric value should be wrapped in XML tags also.
Then you can get it. https://eval.in/51568

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your values in XML so that they can be accessed.

```
<xml>
   <code>
      <codedesc>Code Name</codedesc>
      <value>100</value>
   </code>
   <code>
      <codedesc>Code Name 2</codedesc>
      <value>200</value>
   </code>
</xml>
```

You can then access them like so:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);

echo $xml->code[0]->value;     //100
echo $xml->code[1]->value;     //200
echo $xml->code[1]->codedesc;  //Code Name 2
```

If you can't change your xml, the following should work:

```
echo $xml->code[0];            //100
echo $xml->code[1];            //200
```

Comment: I don't have control over the XML output. I guess I can wrap the values using regex, but I was hoping for something that doesn't require tinkering with the XML itself.

Comment: In that case, with your current setup doing `echo $xml->code[0]; ` should work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to get SimpleXML correctly parses your XML string, and returns a class with an array called 'code', that has 2 objects called codedesc:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [code] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [codedesc] => Code Name
                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [codedesc] => Code Name 2
                )

        )

)
```

If you're trying to get to the values (100, 200) - try putting them in XML elements.

If you're trying to print the entire XML, try `print_r($XML->asXML())` (see [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php))

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to get the 100 and 200 values.